# How can I inject callable into Symfon2 Dependency Injection Container service

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, guzzle

Given the the following class definition

```
class CacheSubscriber implements SubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        CacheStorageInterface $cache,
        callable $canCache
    ) {
        $this->storage = $cache;
        $this->canCache = $canCache;
    }
```

I want to define this class as a service in Symfony2 DIC.

While it is relatively clear what to do with the first argument

```
<service id="nsp_generic.guzzle.subscriber.cache" class="GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Cache\CacheSubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="nsp_generic.redis.cache"/>
    <!-- ??? -->
</service>
```

How can I define and inject the second argument?

**UPDATE**

User meckhardt pushed this into the right direction.

Helper class

```
<?php

namespace Nsp\GenericBundle\Service\Cache;

class CacheConfig {
    public static function canCache() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Service defintion

```
<service id="nsp_generic.guzzle.subscriber.cache" class="GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Cache\CacheSubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="nsp_generic.guzzle.subscriber.cache.storage"/>
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument>Nsp\GenericBundle\Service\Cache\CacheConfig</argument>
        <argument>canCache</argument>
    </argument>
</service>
```

Thanks Martin!

Comment: Why does it need to be a callable? Would probably be better to write a small class around it and inject that.

Comment: Well, the class is inside vendor lib. Wrapping it inside other class is a workaround, would like to solve the problem directly. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: Interesting stuff never thought about it, but the `canCache` seems to be a parameter moreover not callback, you are violating a bit the Single Responsibility Principle doing that. Yep probably best thing to do is to wrap it and then inject.

Comment: I'm just the consumer of the class, I'm sure the signature will improve, just found the problem in itself interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<argument type="collection">
    <argument>ClassName::staticMethod</argument>
</argument>
```

or

```
<argument type="collection">
    <argument type="service" id="serviceId" />
    <argument>instanceMethodName</argument>
</argument>
```

http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score -1):

Maybe create an dependency injection factory like in this example: [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html#passing-arguments-to-the-factory-method)

which will return your callable.